# C++ all AT command's for SMS return's ERROR | PC<->Mobile connection via bluetooth & winsocket

Tags: c++, bluetooth, sms, winsock, at-command

I'm creating windows application in C++, which connect's PC with mobile via bluetooth and winsock. Allow's you to call and send messages from mobile via computer.

I'm using AT command's to tell mobile what i want to do. Pair with mobile device and force a call with At command

```
ATD+420******;
```

works perfect, but all commands for handling SMS like

```
AT+CMGL, AT+CMGF, AT+CMGS etc.
```

return's ERROR.

Here is code which connects PC with mobile via bluetooth and socket:

```
SOCKADDR_BTH RemoteEndPoint;
RemoteEndPoint.port = 0;
RemoteEndPoint.addressFamily = AF_BTH;
RemoteEndPoint.btAddr = m_foundDevices[m_deviceIndex].Address.ullLong;
RemoteEndPoint.serviceClassId = HandsfreeServiceClass_UUID;
int BTHAddrLength = sizeof(RemoteEndPoint);

// Create the socket.
if ((m_localSocket = socket(AF_BTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTHPROTO_RFCOMM)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    // handle error.
}

// Connect the socket.
if ((iResult = connect(m_localSocket, (SOCKADDR *)&RemoteEndPoint, sizeof(RemoteEndPoint))) == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    // handle error.
}
```

Notice line

```
RemoteEndPoint.serviceClassId = HandsfreeServiceClass_UUID
```

I think the problem is here, becouse u cant send sms from Handsfree, but when i use another UUID, it doesnt even pair with mobile.

=== Here is just for info, how am i sending and receiving data from mobile ===

```
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN] = "";
const char *sendbuf = "AT+CMGL\r";
int len = (int)strlen(sendbuf);
if ((iResult = send(m_localSocket, sendbuf, len, MSG_OOB)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    // handle error. return ~0
}

if ((iResult = recv(m_localSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    // handle error. return ~0
}
// Here recvbuf == "\r\nERROR\r\n"
```

Thank you for any advices! If you have any question's about problem, i'll kindly explain.
Regards,
Filip.

Comment: That's a ton of code which is usually a sign you haven't isolated the problem to a particular section yet. That's something to consider.

Comment: Regardless of the fact that the code is simple, the upper part of code is just for info how am i communicating with phone device. I know exactly where the problem occurs in the second part and with which AT command's. If you didn't understand some part i can explain it to you :) Anyway its my first post here, so thank you for your remark. Regards, Filip.

Answer (score 1):

I found out, that the problem is in specifying UUID for connection.

I used `RemoteEndPoint.serviceClassId = HandsfreeServiceClass_UUID;`

and that's the thing, u can't send SMS from Handsfree, you can just call, so any advice which UUID should i use, so SMS AT commands should work ?

Thank you.